How to make a Protocol that inherits methods and attributes from a concrete class
Scenario
I have a Foo protocol:
class Foo(Protocol):
    fooname: str

    def do_fooey_things(self):
        pass

and a bunch of different types of concrete Foos:
class PurpleFoo:
    fooname: str = "purple"

    def do_fooey_things(self):
        print("purple foo!")

What I've achieved with this is a way of being able to type-hint, have my IDE help me, and run tests to make sure all my concrete Foos are doing what I expect: isinstance(purple_foo, Foo). And I've met another design requirement which is I want to minimize abstraction (ie I don't want to use abstract base classes).
But now I need all my Foo's to use a mixin from a third party library like:
class PurpleFoo(BarMixin):
    ...

But now my IDE can't help me with the BarMixin methods and attributes, and my isinstance checks will pass even if one of the Foos fails to use BarMixin (and I want them all too use it).
Question and what I've tried
I know I can't do
class Foo(Protocol, BarMixin)
    ...

So what do I do?
The best I've come up with so far is to make Foo have class attributes pointing to the attributes and methods of BarMixin that I'm interested in adopting:
class Foo(Protocol)
    fooname: str
    bar_attribute = BarMixin.bar_attribute
    bar_method = BarMixin.bar_method

At least this way I benefit from the IDE help (at least in VSCode) and the isinstance check catches any Foo's that don't inherit from BarMixin.

I tried your code locally, also I have created a dummy class with an attr and one method to mimic BarMixin. I could get the help of VSCode. Regarding the isinstance problem, you might have 2 other options: 1. Create a separate Protocol reflecting BarMixin's interface, which adds another Protocol to maintain; isinstance checks might need adjustment. 2. using a meta class. like FooBarMeta(type) in which you modify the __new__ method. Then class PurpleFoo(metaclass=FooBarMeta). Let me know if you need the code for the second option.

You want to use an abstract base class, not a protocol, to force Foo to implement certain methods (whether via direct definition or inheriting from some other class).

@chepner I have a requirement from a third party to avoid using an ABC. The enforcement is done via an isinstance(PurpleFoo, Foo) in CI.

It's unclear. Is the BarMixin a protocol? Then, post a [mre] with details on the BarMixin. If it's not, why not create a protocol for the BarMixin class by yourself? The typing library doesn't provide an automatic Protocol generator for your need, and it's natural it does not.

@relent95 BarMixin is not a Protocol. It's just a regular class. Maybe I shouldn't have called it a mixin.
I think then the right way is to type hint with Foo | BarMixin
